# Being Smart About Vector Memory Allocation

Tags: c++, vector, performance, memory-management, push-back

Let's say I have to iterate over a potentially very large vector of numbers and copy the even and odd elements into new, separate vectors.  (The source vector may have any proportion of evens to odds; it could be all evens, all odds, or somewhere in-between.)

For simplicity, `push_back` is often used for this sort of thing:

```
for (std::size_t Index; Index < Source.size(); Index++)
{
    if (Source[Index] % 2) Odds.push_back(Source[Index]);
    else Evens.push_back(Source[Index]);
}
```

However, I'm worried that this will be inefficient and be harmful if it's used as part of the implementation for something like a sorting algorithm, where performance is paramount.  QuickSort, for example, involves separating elements much like this.

You could use `reserve()` to allocate memory before-hand so only one allocation is needed, but then you have to iterate over the entire source vector twice - once to count how many elements will need to be sorted out, and once more for the actual copying.

You could, of course, allocate the same amount of space as the source vector's size, since neither new vector will need to hold more than that, but that seems somewhat wasteful.

Is there a better method that I'm missing?  Is `push_back()` usually trusted to manage this sort of thing for the programmer, or can it become burdensome for sensitive algorithms?

Comment: `Odds.reserve(Source.size() / 2 + 1); Evens.reserve(Source.size() / 2 + 1);`

Comment: Why do you think that std::sort will care or be more efficient when the memory is allocated all at once?

Comment: @Cory That's not guaranteed to be enough space; the vector could have all odds, all evens, or somewhere in-between.  @Soren I don't follow.  If you're talking about how `std::sort()` manages its allocations internally (assuming it's not in-place), of course it will be slower if it has to allocate more times than necessary.

Comment: @Maxpm read your question wrong.  My bad!

Comment: @Maxpm: I don't know of any implementation of `std::sort()` that needs to allocate anything, it *does* sort in place.

Comment: @Maxpm: `std::sort` typically uses a variant of quicksort (usually introsort) which in addition to ensuring O(nlog(n)) runtime, is also in-place. (If you want to get really specific, it uses log(n) stack space...).

Comment: @Benjamin Then you can assume it uses some custom-written algorithm, or that it isn't a sorting algorithm at all.  The point is that it's an important place to avoid a bottleneck.

Comment: @Maxpm: I can assume *what* uses some custom-written algorithm?  *What* is an important place to avoid a bottleneck?

Comment: @Maxpm what about counting the number of odd / even elements first and then reserve based upon those metrics?

Comment: @Maxpm -- I think your fundamental thinking is wrong.  What is most efficient depends on how you r memory allocation also works.  In particular how the allocator deals efficently with memory fragmentation on repeated allocs/frees.  The container (Vector,Deque) does not give you access to contiguous memory even it is was allocated that way.  You shoukd assume that the Containers are build to have maximum efficiency on the particular platform.

Comment: @Benjamin Whatever higher-level process requires it.

Comment: @Lea I mentioned that in the question.  See the second paragraph after the code sample.

Comment: @Soren Well, that's what I'm asking.  If you believe that `push_back()` is always so efficient that whatever performance is lost by using it is negligible, feel free to add that as an answer.

Comment: @Maxpm: Eh?? The underlying array for `std::vector` is contiguous (this is specified in the standard). As @Ben said, I have never heard of a `std::sort` implementation that is not in-place. Given these two points, it doesn't seem reasonable that the efficiency of `std::sort` would be affected by how much "extra" space was allocated in your vectors. Unless you're super concerned about space efficiency, just over allocate initially and shrink afterwards.

Comment: @Darren The question is not specific to using `std::sort`.

Comment: @Soren: The underlying array in `std::vector` **is** contiguous. The standard demands this type of behaviour. `std::deque` is not required (and in practice probably isn't) contiguous.

Comment: @Maxpm: The question about `push_back` efficiency is valid, but I can't understand what you're getting at with sorting efficiency. You specifically ask about `quicksort` - any worthwhile implementation **is** in-place, so there's no allocation worry here. If you're worried about a non-in-place sort (`mergesort` maybe) it will only allocate additional space based on the number of elements in the vector - **not** the amount of space allocated to the vector. What am I missing??

Comment: @Darren I didn't specifically ask about QuickSort, I used it as a mere example.  The algorithm can be anything, as long as it requires a source vector's elements to be separated into two or more new vectors based on value.

Comment: Everyone: I'm sorry for the confusion; I just now realized that the question was a bit unclear.  The separating of the source vector's elements is a part of an algorithm that the programmer is writing, and that algorithm needs to be as efficient as possible.  I've edited the question to clarify this.

Comment: If a linear search of your array, before performing another linear search through your array, is too wasteful, then you are just out of luck.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm going to answer the question I think you really meant to ask, which is "should `push_back()` be avoided in the inner loops of heavy algorithms?" rather than what others seem to have read into your post, which is "does it matter if I call push_back before doing an unrelated sort on a large vector?"  Also, I'm going to answer from my experience rather than spend time chasing down citations and peer-reviewed articles.

Your example is basically doing two things that add up to the total CPU cost: it's reading and operating on elements in the input vector, and then it has to insert the elements into the output vector. You're concerned about the cost of inserting elements because:

1. push_back() is constant time (instantaneous, really) when a vector has enough space pre-reserved for an additional element, but slow when you've run out of reserved space.
2. Allocating memory is costly ([`malloc()` is just slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/470683/memory-allocation-deallocation-bottleneck), even when pedants pretend that `new` is something different)
3. Copying a vector's data from one region to another after reallocation [is also slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4008128/one-large-malloc-versus-multiple-smaller-reallocs): when push_back() finds it hasn't got enough space, [it has to go and allocate a bigger vector, then copy all the elements](http://www.tantalon.com/pete/files/gdc04_common_cpp_mistakes_in_games.ppt). (In theory, for vectors that are many OS pages in size, a magic implementation of the STL could use the VMM to move them around in the virtual address space without copying — in practice [I've never seen one that could](http://www.gamedev.net/topic/505481-do-stl-containers-always-move-memory/).)
4. Over-allocating the output vectors causes problems: it causes fragmentation, making future allocations slower; it burns data cache, making everything slower; if persistent, it ties up scarce free memory, leading to disk paging on a PC and a crash on embedded platforms.
5. Under-allocating the output vectors causes problems because reallocating a vector is an O(n) operation, so reallocating it *m* times is O(m×n). If the STL's default allocator uses exponential reallocation (making the vector's reserve twice its previous size every time you realloc), that makes your linear algorithm O(n + n log m).

Your instinct, therefore, is correct: always pre-reserve space for your vectors where possible, not because push_back is slow, but because it can trigger a reallocation that *is* slow. Also, if you look at the implementation of `shrink_to_fit`, you'll see it also does a copy reallocation, temporarily doubling your memory cost and causing further fragmentation.

Your problem here is that you don't always know exactly how much space you'll need for the output vectors; the usual response is to use a heuristic and maybe a custom allocator. Reserve n/2+k of the input size for each of your output vectors by default, where k is some safety margin. That way you'll *usually* have enough space for the output, so long as your input is reasonably balanced, and push_back can reallocate in the rare cases where it's not. If you find that push_back's exponential behavior is wasting too much memory ( causing you to reserve 2n elements when really you just needed n+2 ), you can give it a custom allocator that expands the vector size in smaller, linear chunks — but of course that will be much slower in cases where the vectors are really unbalanced and you end up doing lots of resizes.

There's no way to always reserve the exact right amount of space without walking the input elements in advance; but if you know what the balance *usually* looks like, you can use a heuristic to make a good guess at it for a statistical performance gain over many iterations.

Comment: +1 for the shrink_to_fit-does-a-copy. Just looked at the Microsoft implementation and, indeed...

Answer (score 2):

> You could, of course, allocate the same amount of space as the source
>   vector's size, since neither new vector will need to hold more than
>   that, but that seems somewhat wasteful.

Then follow it up with a call to [`shrink_to_fit`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/shrink_to_fit)

> However, I'm worried that this will be inefficient and harm things
>   like sorting algorithms. ... Is push_back() usually trusted to manage
>   this sort of thing for the programmer, or can it become burdensome for
>   sensitive algorithms?

Yes, push_back is trusted.  Although honestly I don't understand what your concern is.  Presumably, if you're using algorithms on the vector, you've already put the elements into the vector.  What kind of algorithm are you talking about where it would matter *how* the vector elements got there, be it `push_back` or something else?

Comment: To be clear, the programmer is the person writing the algorithm.  He's not calling `std::sort` or anything - the vector-splitting is a part of the algorithm he is writing, and the algorithm needs to be as efficient as possible.

Comment: @Maxpm: Then, unless you're talking about positively massive* datasets, I would just go with the full-sized reserve, followed by the algorithm you showed in your post, followed by shrink_to_fit.  -- I'm defining positively massive here loosely as ~10% of your total system memory.

Answer (score 2):

How about sorting the original vector with a custom predicate that puts all the evens before all the odds?

```
bool EvenBeforeOdd(int a, int b)
{
  if ((a - b)  % 2 == 0) return a < b;

  return a % 2 == 0;
}

std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), EvenBeforeOdd);
```

Then you just have to find the largest even number, which you can do e.g. with `upper_bound` for a very large even number or something like that. Once you found that, you can make very cheap copies of the ranges.

**Update:** As @Blastfurnace commented, it's much more efficient to use `std::partition` rather than `sort`, since we don't actually need the elements ordered within each partition:

```
bool isEven(int a) { return 0 == a % 2; }
std::vector<int>::const_iterator it =  std::partition(v.begin(), v.end(), isEven);

std::vector<int> evens, odds;
evens.reserve(std::distance(v.begin(), it);
odds.reserve(std::distance(it, v.end());

std::copy(v.begin(), it, std::back_inserter(evens));
std::copy(it, v.end(), std::back_inserter(odds));
```

Comment: If he's just copying the elements to two destination vectors then using `std::partition_copy` is simpler and probably much faster.

Comment: @Blastfurnace: Yes, very nice! Is `partition_copy` new in C++0x? But even `partition` is a much better idea than mine. I'll add that!

Answer (score 1):

If your objects are created dynamically then the vectors are literally just storing pointers. This makes the vectors considerably more efficient, especially when it comes to internal reallocation. This would also save memory if same objects exist in multiple locations.

```
std::vector<YourObject*> Evens;
```

Note: Do not push pointers from context of function as this will cause data corruption outside of that frame. Instead objects would need to be allocated dynamically.

This might not solve your problem, but perhaps it is of use.

Comment: This is rarely ever a good idea.  The motivation for doing this is usually the result of a severe underestimation of just how smart library writers are.  It certainly is not in any way helpful in this case since we are talking about integers.

Answer (score 1):

If your sub vectors are exactly half (odd / even) then simply allocate 50% of original vector for each. This would avoid wastage and `shrink_to_fit`.